# Split view with one panel scrollable

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a layout where there is a div with a **max height**, and inside that, there are two divs. One div (the footer), has a fixed height (55px). The other is a scrollable div where the height will increase/decrease according to it's content.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="panel">
      Scrollable Div
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
      Fixed footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The scrollable div height should always fit it's content. But when the max height is exceeded (`.wrapper has a max-height of 300px`), it should only take up the remaining space minus the footer height without affecting the footer's position.

But what I achieved of this layout is not according to my requirement.

In my example, when content gets added into the scrollable div, the footer gets pushed out of the wrapper. What should happen is the footer to remain at the bottom of the wrapper (without getting cut off), and the scrollable div to span its height upwards.

**Please note I'm trying NOT to use position: fixed or absolute.**

This is for a mobile app so fixed positions causes a lot of bugs.

Here is the JS Fiddle of what I have so far,
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3anmo6g/)

Answer (score 0):

set the `max-height:300px` to the `.panel` div instead

JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c3anmo6g/1/)